# Can we merge if else condition in a single test class method?

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

I am writing test class to test trigger which has many-many `status` and `sub-status` values. I developed below test method and one more test method (which I've not shown), but the only difference is that  `c.IsFirstRequest = false;` and `c.IsFirstRequest = true;`  These both test methods give 100% code coverage. I'm testing various SLA of the entitlement processes through test class.

Can we write both conditions in the same method ? If yes, then how ?

I have almost `10 category` and these are getting distinguished based on some fields. I have decided to keep a single test method to cover each `Category` and covered all the `SubStatus` values of it. So that I will be creating 20 test class methods for 20 SubCategories. Please guide.

```
public static testMethod void testMethod1(){
    Test.startTest();
    Account acc = new Account(Name='Test Account');
    insert acc;

    .............
    ..............
    ...............

    Case c = new Case();
    c.RecordTypeId = '123456789';
    c.Category__c = 'XXXXXX';
    c.SubCategory__c = 'YYYYY';
    c.Priority = 'Normal';
    c.IsFirstRequest = false;
    c.Status = 'New';
    c.SubStatus__c = 'KKKK';
    c.EntitlementId = ent.Id;

    List<Case> cases = new List<Case>();
    cases.add(c);
    insert cases;

    c.Status = 'Pending';
    c.SubStatus__c = 'OOOOOOO';
    update c;

    ...............
    ................

    c.Status = 'Closed';
    update c;  
    .................
    .................

    System.assert(completionDts != null);        
    Test.stopTest();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your code, but you could probably cover everything in a single unit test; your primary mistake is that you're testing everything one at a time, instead of as a batch:

```
Test.startTest();
Account acc = new Account(Name='Test Account');
insert acc;

.............
..............
...............

Case c = new Case();
c.RecordTypeId = '123456789';
c.Category__c = 'XXXXXX';
c.SubCategory__c = 'YYYYY';
c.Priority = 'Normal';
c.IsFirstRequest = false;
c.Status = 'New';
c.SubStatus__c = 'KKKK';
c.EntitlementId = ent.Id;

List<Case> cases = new List<Case>();
cases.add(c.clone(false));
cases.add(c.clone(false));
cases.add(c.clone(false));
cases.add(c.clone(false));
insert cases;

cases[0].Status = 'Pending';
cases[0].SubStatus__c = 'OOOOOOO';
cases[1].Status = 'In Progress';
cases[1].SubStatus__c = 'IIIIIIIII';
cases[2].Status = 'In Progress';
cases[2].SubStatus__c = 'Available';
cases[3].Status = 'Closed';
cases[3].SubStatus__c = 'Available';
update cases;
```

You should probably do this as a decent test anyways, simply to prove that your code will not crash when cases are uploaded in a batch.

Comment: Thanks for good guidance ! This works fine. What does `cases.add(c.clone(false));` mean ? Could you please explain in more detailed ? We know in process flow, lots of Case status, substatus changes, so I like this approach

Comment: Also please guide on System.Assert(??)

Comment: @user4567570 For clone, see [sObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm); the parameter really isn't necessary, but I wrote it that way. For your System.assert, you should be using them to verify the expected output. Only you can say what that means for sure, but it may well include changed fields, related records updated or created, etc. There's plenty of examples out there to look at.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you extract your object creation into a method - that way you'll have less clutter in your test method, and it easily solves your problem:

```
public static Case createTestCase(boolean isFirstRequest)
{
    return new Case(
        isFirstRequest = isFirstRequest,
        c.RecordTypeId = '123456789',
        ...
    );
}
```

Now your code can just be:

```
Case c = createTestCase(false), d = createTestCase(true);
List<Case> cases = new List<Case>{c, d};
insert cases;
```

You can also use the sObject `clone` method:

```
Case c = new Case();
c.isFirstRequest = false;
...
Case d = c.clone();
d.isFirstRequest = true;
List<Case> cases = new List<Case>{c, d};
insert cases;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Boolean> booleans = new List<Boolean>
booleans.add(true);
booleans.add(false);

for ( Boolean b : booleans ) {
    Case c = new Case();
    c.IsFirstRequest = b;
    c.RecordTypeId = '123456789';
    c.ELC_Category__c = 'XXXXXX';
    ...
}
```

Comment: For another category, I followed this approach get System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries: 101

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? I get what you're going for, but code-only answers are discouraged.

Comment: @user4567570 then you have a SOQL query in your `for` loop which is a bad practice.