# How to write test method for the Map<Id, Case> oldCasesMap = (Map<Id, Case>)oldSobjsMap;

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

I am taking a reference from the link: [Can we merge if else condition in a single test class method?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/187502/can-we-merge-if-else-condition-in-a-single-test-class-method/187507#187507). I have a code something like below and I want to write the test class for it.

```
Map<Id, Case> oldCasesMap = (Map<Id, Case>)oldSobjsMap;
if(cs.Category__c == 'Basic Authorization'){
    if(cs.SubCategory == 'Auth.Net'){                     
        if(oldCasesMap != null){
            Case oldCs = oldCasesMap.get(cs.Id);                               
                if(cs.Status == 'XXXX' && cs.SubStatus == 'YYYY' && 
                    oldCs.Status == 'MMMM' && oldCs.SubStatus == 'NNNN'){
                        caseIds.add(cs.Id);
                        MilestoneUtils.completeMilestone(caseIds, milestoneNames, System.now());
                    }else if(cs.Status == 'OOOO' && cs.SubStatus == 'LLLL'){
                        caseIds.add(cs.Id);
                        MilestoneUtils.completeMilestone(caseIds, milestoneNames, System.now());
                    }
                }
            }   
        }
```

I am not sure why the test class not covering the If part. I have written a test method like below.

```
public static testMethod void testLabelReviewRequest(){
        Test.startTest();
        Account acc = new Account(Name='Test');
        insert acc;

        Id entProcessId = [SELECT Id FROM SlaProcess WHERE SObjectType = 'Case' 
                                   AND Name LIKE '%XXXXXX%' AND IsActive = true LIMIT 1].Id;

        Entitlement ent = new Entitlement(Name='Sample Name', AccountId =acc.Id,
                                        SLAProcessId = entProcessId, Type='Phone Support');
        insert ent;

        Case c = new Case();
        c.RecordTypeId = '123456';
        c.Category = 'QQQQ';
        c.SubCategory = 'WWWW';
        ...........
        ...........

        List<Case> cases = new List<Case>();
        cases.add(c.clone(false));
        ...............
        insert cases;

        cases[0].Status = 'Pending';
        cases[0].SubStatus = 'LLLL';
        cases[1].Status = 'In Progress';
        cases[1].SubStatus = 'KKKKK';
        cases[2].Status = 'In Progress';
        cases[2].SubStatus = 'GGGG';
        cases[3].Status = 'CCCC';
        update cases;          
        Test.stopTest();
    }
```

What modifications do I need to make in order to cover the oldMap code?

Comment: How is this not an exact duplicate? https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/187502/can-we-merge-if-else-condition-in-a-single-test-class-method You should update your previous post with any missing information. Please revisit the [help], [tour], [faq], and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

After inserting the cases, query the list of of cases and then assign the values and finally update.

Create the values which will satisfy the conditions.

```
Entitlement ent = new Entitlement(Name='Sample Name', AccountId =acc.Id,
                                        SLAProcessId = entProcessId, Type='Phone Support');
insert ent;

Case c = new Case();
c.RecordTypeId = '123456';
c.Category = 'QQQQ';
c.SubCategory = 'WWWW';
c.EntitlementId = ent.Id;
c.Status = 'MMMM';
c.SubStatus = 'NNNN';
...........
...........

List<Case> cases = new List<Case>();
cases.add(c.clone(false));
...............
Database.SaveResult[] result = database.insert(cases);
Set<id> Ids = new Set<Id>();
for(Database.SaveResult sr : srList)
{
    Ids.add(sr.getId());
}
List<Case> lstCase = [SELECT Status,SubStatus FROM Case WHERE Id IN:Ids]; 

lstCase[0].Status = 'Pending';
lstCase[0].SubStatus = 'LLLL';
lstCase[1].Status = 'In Progress';
lstCase[1].SubStatus = 'KKKKK';
lstCase[2].Status = 'In Progress';
lstCase[2].SubStatus = 'GGGG';
lstCase[3].Status = 'CCCC';
update lstCase;          
Test.stopTest();
```