# Why can we use != null while writting Apex Test class?

Tags: apex, unit-test

I am developing a `Test classes` for the `Milestones` and `Entitlement processes` by taking a reference from : [Can we merge if else condition in a single test class method?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/187502/can-we-merge-if-else-condition-in-a-single-test-class-method) . I am getting error

```
Expression cannot be a statement
```

The test class below for reference::

```
public static testMethod void testQQQQ(){
        Test.startTest();
        Account acc = new Account(Name='Account');
        insert acc;

        .............
        .............

        Case c = new Case();
        ..........
        ..........

        List<Case> cases = new List<Case>();
        cases.add(c.clone(false));
        ................
        ..............
        insert cases;

        cases[0].Status = 'XXXX';
        cases[0].SubStatus = 'XXXX';
        update cases;
        cases[0].SubStatus != 'YYYYY'; // line-22
        update cases;                
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Basically, I wanted to test the below condition::

```
if(oldCs.Status == 'XXXX' && oldCs.SubStatus == 'XXXX' && cs.SubStatus != 'YYYYY'){
    cs.addError(OOOOOOOOOOO');
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only valid operations for **assigning** a value to a field are **assignment operators**, which are "=", ">>=", "<<=", ">>>=", "&=", "|=", "+=", "-=", "*=" and "/=". Other operators with equals, such as "!=", "==", "===", "<=", ">=", are **Boolean operators**, and cannot assign a value to a field. Simply assign any value that's not 'YYYYY' (case insensitive) in order to pass the test.

For example, the following would pass:

```
    cases[0].SubStatus = 'YYYYZ'; // line-22
```

Comment: Actually I need to strictly checked the condition for `cs.SubStatus != 'Request Submitted' `, because otherwise my validation is not passing.

Comment: @user4567570 If there's validation preventing it, then it's not possible for your code to execute. You can't test impossible conditions.

Comment: Any workaround in setting value cs.SubStatus != 'Request Submitted' in test class ?

Comment: @user4567570 You'd have to set it to a specific value, like `cs.SubStatus = 'Request Not Submitted'`. If you're not able to set such a value because of validation, you won't be able to test your code.

Answer (score 0):

Apex has this limitation.
you can't use conditional expression without assigning to a variable or using it in a condition statement (while, if, etc).
For example, none of the following should compile when written as stand-alone expressions.

i != 95;
i < 75;
i > 75;

And as per your code what line 22 defines ? it has to be in if or some another conditional block as per apex.

Comment: Very weird limitation. It stop developer to test complex things for sure ! Now Guide me how I will test that condition ?

Comment: what is that condition you want to test ?
You are inserting cases. Then changing First case record status to 'xxxx'.

Comment: Added details above in my posts. remember I am working on Entitlements, so I need to check all the status & sub status values while saving the case.

Comment: missing this ' in addError('0000000')

Comment: You've not posted the code you're testing. From what you have shared, best thing would be to query the results after Insert for the condition and assert that it's != to 'yyyy'.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to test since your question is not clear, but as @sfdcfox said, you're using a boolean operator as if it were an assignment operator.

Assuming you want to do an assignment and something similar to the C# `??` operator, you have to do it the long way:

```
x = (y != null) ? y : z;
```

In case you're trying to test your code with assertions, then you might be looking for the `System` assertion methods:

```
System.assertNotEquals('YYYYZ', cases[0].SubStatus);
```